# wxpython controlling a widget with the id

Tags: wxpython

hey :)
ok im looking for a way to create a large number of panels in wxpython and append a hold to them in a list but am not sure how best to do this. for example
for i in list:
wx.Panel(self, -1, pos, size) #create the panel

## somehow store a hold to it e.g

anotherlist.append(a) #where a is the hold to the panel
when i say hold i mean say the variable name is x, so
x = wx.Panel. i would call x the hold cos x can be used for any manipulation of the widget, e.g x.SetPosition etc.. i was thinking maybe using a class something(wx.Panel) that creates the panel and saves the id of the panel.. problem is having the id i have no idea how to access the widget. say the panels id is -206. how do i do something like widgetid(-206).SetBackgroundColour("RED")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people solve these sorts of things by creating the ids at the beginning of the file:

```
panelOneId = wx.NewId()
panelTwoId = wx.NewId()
```

And then doing something like myPanel = wx.FindWindowById(panelOneId). Of course, if all you're doing is setting panel attributes, it might just behoove you to create a helper method like this:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def createPanel(self, sizer, id, bg):
    """"""
    panel = wx.Panel(self, id=id)
    panel.SetBackgroundColour(bg)
    sizer.Add(panel)
```

You can also use wx.FindWindowByName, if you've given the panels unique name parameters.

Comment: thank you so much mike wx.FindWindowById is exactly what i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a dictionary to map ids to panels

```
panels = {}
for i in range(100):
    id = wx.NewId()
    panels[id] = wx.Panel(parent, id, ...)
```

You then have access to a list of ids (`.keys()`), a list of panels (`.values()`) and a mapping from id to panel.

Comment: it would seem as mike said tho, that wx.FindWindowById() is basically the same and you dont have to create the dictionary anyway as wx.FindWindowById(20) would return the wx.Panel(self, id=20) object... thanks tho answer definitely is usefull